# mlpack Armadillo Dependency setting by cmake,error:The source directory "C:/mlpack/armadillo/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, mlpack

Build Environment:win10 vs 16 2019

When I used cMake to set Armadillo Dependency like this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" ..
```

it always sends me CMake error:

```
The source directory "C:/mlpack/armadillo/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

I just followed the tips from [mlpack](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/mlpack-3.2.2/doxygen/build_windows.html).

Comment: The last parameter to the `cmake` specifies the **source directory**, with `CMakeLists.txt` file in it. In you case this should be a top directory with downloaded Armadillo. If you follow the instructions: create `build` directory under that top directory and call `cmake` from the created directory, then source directory could be addressed via `..` (one directory upper). You can always use **absolute path** to the source directory in the last `cmake` parameter.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your answer.But I'm still confused.Because it's my first time to learn about cmake.So u means that I have to change DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" ..?    Could you give me the correct codes,or point what I should do specifically? I'm just a green hand

Comment: **Instead** of the last parameter - `..` - use **absolute path** to the top directory with downloaded Armadillo. You don't specify where you have Armadillo downloaded, so it is impossible to be more precise. Possibly, this is `C:/mlpack/armadillo` directory.

Comment: I downloaded armadillo to C:/mlpack/armadillo indeed.

Comment: I tried the code as :cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" C:/mlpack/armadillo

Comment: always: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/mlpack/armadillo" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Are there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: [This Armadillo repo](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code) contains `CMakeLists.txt` in the top directory. Probably, you have downloaded something else.

Comment: There two files in the path :"C:\mlpack\armadillo\armadillo-9.860.2".One called "InstallFiles" contains ArmadilloConfig.cmake.in and  ArmadilloConfigVersion.cmake.in.Another called "Modules" contains "ARMA_FindACML.cmake" and "ARMA_FindACMLMP.cmake" etc.Are they what I need?

Comment: What you have resembles [cmake_aux/](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/tree/9.900.x/cmake_aux) subdirectory in the repo. You cannot "build" that subdirectory.

Comment: I finded a Cmakelists in armadillo-9.860.2,and I copied it to the build files,then ran my code.It said:CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will become a fatal error in future CMake releases.                                                           
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
Can't read
C:/mlpack/armadillo/build/include/armadillo_bits/arma_version.hpp

Comment: The 70 to 73 lines in the Cmakelists is: 
 set(ARMA_VERSION_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/armadillo_bits/arma_version.hpp")

if(NOT EXISTS ${ARMA_VERSION_FILE_NAME})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't read ${ARMA_VERSION_FILE_NAME}")
endif()

Comment: Do not try to "fix" what you have by copiing separate files. Just **clone** the repo and build it following the instructions.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand clone the rope.....Did you say that I have to use git to do something?

Comment: I just find that if I follow the instructions from mlpack official,I have to use cmake in some files,but all of them do not contain cMakelists.What's wrong happened?

Comment: [git clone repository](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+clone+repository)

Comment: I guess I have to give up  and try to use ubuntu .Thank you very much.